# Tableau Reverse Proxy Issue

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, tableau-api

I want to make Tableau (which is on an internal network) accessible on the public network. One of the ways recommended by Tableau Support is a Reverse Proxy.

I have set up the required modules and have the reverse proxy functioning. The login page is available through these settings in httpd given below. However, once I log in and want to open Projects, Views etc. It routes to

```
http://actualsite.com/#/vieworproject
```

which should actually be `http://actualsite.com/tableauaccess/#/vieworproject`.

Here is the httpd configuration:

```
 ProxyPass       /tableauaccess/  http://tableauserverexample.com/
 ProxyPassReverse       /tableauaccess/  http://tableauserverexample.com/

<Location /tableauaccess/>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
ProxyHTMLURLMap  /  /tableauaccess/
</Location>
```

This doesnt solve the main issue with #. I tried

```
ProxyPass       /#/  http://tableauserverexample.com/#/
ProxyPassReverse       /#/  http://tableauserverexample.com/#
```

But it doesnt help. Any suggestions?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We had this same issue recently. Your httpd.conf file is technically correct for mod_proxy, however the url you are attempting to use is not supported by Tableau. You cannot use:

```
http://actualsite.com/tableauaccess
```

But rather you must use the format:

```
http://tableauaccess.actualsite.com
```

We ended up setting up that sub-domain name and then using a VirtualHost block such as:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName actualsite.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/path2/pathx"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tableauaccess.actualsite.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://tableauaccess.actualsite.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://tableauaccess.actualsite.com/
    <IfModule mod_cache.c>
       CacheDisable *
    </IfModule>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http" #or "https", depending on preference
</VirtualHost>
```

Be sure to double-check your Tableau server to update the URL format.

Sources:
https://community.tableau.com/thread/198095
https://community.tableau.com/thread/218678
(I don't have enough reputation points to post all of my sources, but thanks to Tableau community, shanemadden at ServerFault, and the Apache documentation.)

edit: forgot trailing slashes